# Python crawler finds desired tags in only first few divs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape some images from a shopping site (https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw) but I am having some trouble with it since the listings updates as you scroll. I am trying to get the image source in the HTML tag below:

[image: HTML tags I am trying to retrieve]

Now the code I have been using is shown below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

listing = soup.select('.listing-cover-photo ')
for item in listing:
    print(item.select('img'))
```

The problem is that although it does find the  tag for every listing, it can only find the  tag for the first 6 listings. The output from my code is shown below:

OUTPUT:

```
[<img alt="Off-White Off White Caravaggio Hoodie" src="https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:480,height:640,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/yX8vvvBsTaugadX0jssT"/>]
(...a few more of these...)
[<img alt="Off-White Off-White Arrows Hoodie Black" src="https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:480,height:640,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/9CMvJoQIRaqgtK0u9ov0"/>]
[]
[]
[]
[]
(...many more empty lists...)
```

This persists even if loop through all pages in the side (adding '?page = n' to the url) and shows only the first 6 entries of each page.

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the **src** attributes of the `<img>` tags within the [shopping site](https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.grailed.com/shop/EkpEBRw4rw')
  print([my_image.get_attribute("src") for my_image in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.listing-cover-photo>img")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/yX8vvvBsTaugadX0jssT', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/YjiErjJNQrarKGDuGr3S', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/G9CwIli8QUW3uGgZeirk', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/Ta9DAxg4SeKAT6kBLyJo', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/QglmTKyTxu31PeDFWFnw', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/9CMvJoQIRaqgtK0u9ov0', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/MCJY9cSQsiSU4TlSTcD7', 'https://process.fs.grailed.com/AJdAgnqCST4iPtnUxiGtTz/cache=expiry:max/rotate=deg:exif/resize=width:240,height:320,fit:crop/output=format:webp,quality:70/compress/https://cdn.fs.grailed.com/api/file/L4NHu1ByT3Kwn8dRsdBX']
  ```

Comment: This is definitely a better way to get the **src** attribute than what I was trying, but unfortunately it only still returns the link for the first 6 images in the site.

Comment: @GabrielBello I could have suggested a dozen of improvements in your script but that wouldn't have been helpful. I saw your code trials with _BeautifulSoup_. So I tried to answer your question using only _Selenium_. Perhaps based on my solution now you can easily extract all the **src** attributes (more then 6) else feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements. StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.